# Sequence Convergence proof check

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I am trying to solve the following sequence question:

> Show that $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $A$ if and only if $\{a_n - A\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $0$.

Proof: Assume $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $A$. Then for each epsilon > 0, there exist N such that for all n>=N, abs($\{a_n\}$- $A$) < epsilon. Now consider the sequence $\{a_n - A\}_{n=1}^\infty$. For this sequence to converge, it must be that for each epsilon > 0, there exist P such that for each n>=P, abs($\{a_n - A\}$ - $B$) < epsilon. Let $B$ = 0, so we have abs($\{a_n\}$- $A$) < epsilon. Since we know that abs($\{a_n\}$- $A$) < epsilon when n>=N, it follows that N=P. Therefore, since there exist this P where for all n>=P, abs($\{a_n - A\}$ - $B$) < epsilon, $\{a_n - A\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $0$.

This is only the proof for the first assumption.

Answer (score 1):

(1) $a_n \to A \Rightarrow \forall \epsilon>0, \exists N$ such that $|a_n-A|< \epsilon, \forall n >n$. To have $(a_n-A) \to 0$ then we need that for a given $\epsilon, \exists N_0$ s.t $|a_n - A - 0| = |a_n - A|< \epsilon$ for all $n >N_0$. Just take $N_0 = N$ from above.

(2) If $(a_n-A) \to 0$ then given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N_1$ s.t $|a_n - A - 0| = |a_n-A|< \epsilon$ for all $n>N_1$ but again if you choose $N = N_1$ in the definition of $a_n \to A$ then you are done.

Answer (score -1):

Looks good. You can actually prove both directions at once as follows:

$\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $A$ if and only if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\vert a_n - A \vert < \epsilon$, which is true if and only $\{a_n - A\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $0$.

Comment: This is exactly what the OP is trying to prove.